# Vue v-html not properly displaying my elements

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, katex

I have a given HTML string that I need to display in my Vue component.

*Context: KaTeX is a typesetting library that renders mathematical syntax into easy to read equations.*

**Here is the string:**

```
<p>A pintail population, <div v-katex="'p'"></div>, of <div v-katex="'1000'"></div> bacteria tows in number according to the equation <div v-katex="'\\displaystyle p(t) = 1000(1 + \\frac{4t}{t^2+ 50})'"></div>, where <div v-katex="'t'"></div> is in hours. Find the rate which the population is growing after <div v-katex="'1 h'"></div> and after <div v-katex="'2h'"></div>.</p>
```

**Here it is in my code:**
*renderKatex() returns a String of HTML code.*

[image]

**Here it is in the web browser dev tools:**

[image]

**But here it is displayed:**

[image]

As you can see, the `<div v-katex>` elements are not showing up. Except, when I hardcode the previous HTML in the template (I copied and pasted the HTML from dev-tools), it displays:

[image]

**Displayed:**

[image]

So there seems to be some issue with the Vue directive "v-html" that doesn't render the elements properly.

Comment: There is a particular reason to put both `"` and `'` in your katex properties? like here: `v-katex="'p'"`

Comment: the directive=`v-katex` is one wrapper for `v-html`? could you share the codes for the implementation of `v-katex`? or your project references one library, if so, please share the link.

Comment: When you use `v-html` Vue simply assigns the value to the `innerHTML` of its corresponding DOM node - but it does not treat the `v-html` value as a Vue template and does not process it in any way. So your `v-katex` will not be treated as Vue directive (and executed) but like an ordinary HTML attribute with no particular meaning.

Comment: IVO nailed it. From the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML): "...[`v-html` contents are] interpreted as plain HTML - data bindings are ignored. Note that you cannot use `v-html` to compose template partials, because Vue is not a string-based templating engine. Instead, components are preferred as the fundamental unit for UI reuse and composition."